# Can't insert graph in a wxPython GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, plot, wxpython

I am trying to make a telemetry software for a college project, that's why I'm using wxPython to make a GUI. I'm currently trying to make a function that displays a graph of brake_p and throttle in function of the time after I opened the entry file.
The code looks good to me, however it looks like there is an error inside the module that blocks me from succeeding.

Here is the error I get when I open the entry file :

```
> PS C:\Users\Adrie\OneDrive\Bureau\telemetry python>  &
> 'C:\Users\Adrie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe'
> 'c:\Users\Adrie\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '54993' '--' 'c:\Users\Adrie\OneDrive\Bureau\telemetry
> python\v0601.py'  Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "c:\Users\Adrie\OneDrive\Bureau\telemetry python\v0601.py", line 105,
> in OnOpen self.OpenData(file) File
> "c:\Users\Adrie\OneDrive\Bureau\telemetry python\v0601.py", line 144,
> in OpenData self.canvas.Draw(self.drawBrakeThrottlePlot) File
> "C:\Users\Adrie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\wx\lib\plot\plotcanvas.py",
> line 1750, in Drawgraphics.logScale = self.logScale AttributeError:
> 'method' object has no attribute 'logScale' PS
> C:\Users\Adrie\OneDrive\Bureau\telemetry python>
```

The error I can't understand is the part in bold caracters,as it is nowhere in my code :
**Drawgraphics.logScale = self.logScale
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'logScale'**

I 'd like to add I plan to add a bar marker on the graph that would be either automatically move at real-time, or either movable by the user so the time at the marker would be used to display in other widget data corresponding to the exact instant (like in the matlab simulink graph/scopes), which means I can't store the graph as a bitmap but really as a graph/plot.

I tried to switch to another library to import the plot into the wxFrame but I just can't make it work as they look more complicated to me, so I got back to this method.

Here is the code :

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wx.lib.plot import PlotCanvas, PlotGraphics, PolyLine, PolyMarker
import wxmplot.interactive as wi

# Variables initialization
time, speed, distance, brake_p, throttle, g_x, g_y, g_z, gps_x, gps_y, omega_fl, omega_fr = ([] for i in range(12))
r=1     # Wheel radius, will implement a feature to make it editable by the user later

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        # Create a panel and add it to the main window
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        # Set the panel as the main window's sizer
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        # Set the window's min size
        self.SetMinSize((1280,720))

        # create a menu bar
        self.makeMenuBar()

        # and a status bar
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("v 0.1")

        # put some text with a larger bold font on it
        st = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Welcome on the EFT's Telemetry software !")
        font = st.GetFont()
        font.PointSize += 10
        font = font.Bold()
        st.SetFont(font)

        # and create a sizer to manage the layout of child widgets
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(st, wx.SizerFlags().Border(wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, 25))
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def makeMenuBar(self):
        # Make a file menu with Hello and Exit items
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        # The "\t..." syntax defines an accelerator key that also triggers
        # the same event
        openItem = fileMenu.Append(-1, "&Open...\tCtrl-O",
                "Open a data file")
        fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
        # When using a stock ID we don't need to specify the menu item's
        # label
        exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)

        # Now a help menu for the about item
        helpMenu = wx.Menu()
        aboutItem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT)

        # Now a view menu for the view item
        # viewMenu = wx.Menu()
        # aboutItem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_VIEW)

        # Make the menu bar and add the two menus to it. The '&' defines
        # that the next letter is the "mnemonic" for the menu item. On the
        # platforms that support it those letters are underlined and can be
        # triggered from the keyboard.

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")
        menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&Help")
        # menuBar.Append(viewMenu, "&View")

        # Give the menu bar to the frame
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        # Finally, associate a handler function with the EVT_MENU event for
        # each of the menu items. That means that when that menu item is
        # activated then the associated handler function will be called.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, openItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit,  exitItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, aboutItem)

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox("This is a simple Telemetry software project.",
                    wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

    def drawBrakeThrottlePlot():
        data1 = PolyLine([time, brake_p], legend='Brake Pressure (%)',  colour='red', width='1')
        data2 = PolyLine([time, throttle], legend='Throttle (%)', colour='green', width='1') 
        return PlotGraphics([data1, data2], "Real Time Brake Pressure and Throttle", "Time (ms)", "Relative Value (%)")

    def OnOpen(self, event):
         # Create the file dialog
        with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open Data file", wildcard="text files (*.txt)|*.txt",
                        style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:

            if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return     # the user changed their mind

            # Proceed loading the file chosen by the user
            pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
            try:
                with open(pathname, 'r') as file:
                    self.OpenData(file)
            except IOError:
                wx.LogError("Cannot open file '%s'." % pathname)

    def OpenData(self, file):
        data = file.readlines()  # On assigne à L toutes les lignes du fichier
        nb_lignes = len(data)  # On assigne à nb_lignes la longueur de L
        file.close()

        for i in range(nb_lignes):
            data[i] = data[i].strip('\n')
            temp = data[i].split()
            time.append(float(temp[0]))
            speed.append((float(temp[8])+float(temp[9]))*r/2)
            distance.append(speed[i]*1/1000) # Ici 1/1000 correspond à la fréquence d'échantillonage, modifiable en fx du capteur
            brake_p.append(float(temp[1]))
            throttle.append(float(temp[2]))
            g_x.append(float(temp[3]))
            g_y.append(float(temp[4]))
            g_z.append(float(temp[5]))
            gps_x.append(float(temp[6]))
            gps_y.append(float(temp[7]))
            omega_fl.append(float(temp[8]))
            omega_fr.append(float(temp[9]))



        # Remove the text on the panel
        for child in self.GetChildren():
            child.Destroy()

        # create a panel and add it to the main window
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        # Create the plot
        self.canvas = PlotCanvas(panel)
        self.canvas.Draw(self.drawBrakeThrottlePlot)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.createControls(panel), 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add((-1, 10))
        self.sizer.Add(self.createButtonBar(panel), 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)

    def createControls(self, panel):
        box = wx.StaticBox(panel, -1, 'Data')
        sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box, wx.VERTICAL)
        grid = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        txt1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Time (s)')
        grid.Add(txt1, (1, 0))
        self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(80, -1))
        grid.Add(self.tc1, (1, 1))
        txt2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Speed (km/h)')
        grid.Add(txt2, (2, 0))
        self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(80, -1))
        grid.Add(self.tc2, (2, 1))
        txt3 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'RPM')
        grid.Add(txt3, (3, 0))
        self.tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(80, -1))
        grid.Add(self.tc3, (3, 1))
        txt4 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Brake pressure')
        grid.Add(txt4, (4, 0))
        self.tc4 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(80, -1))
        grid.Add(self.tc4, (4, 1))
        txt5 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Throttle position')
        grid.Add(txt5, (5, 0))
        self.tc5 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(80, -1))
        grid.Add(self.tc5, (5, 1))
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        return sizer

    def createButtonBar(self, panel):
        """
        Create the buttons at the bottom of the panel
        """
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.zoomInButton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Zoom In")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnZoomIn, self.zoomInButton)
        sizer.Add(self.zoomInButton, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.zoomOutButton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Zoom Out")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnZoomOut, self.zoomOutButton)
        sizer.Add(self.zoomOutButton, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.panLeftButton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Pan Left")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPanLeft, self.panLeftButton)
        sizer.Add(self.panLeftButton, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.panRightButton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Pan Right")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPanRight, self.panRightButton)
        sizer.Add(self.panRightButton, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.resetButton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Reset")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnReset, self.resetButton)
        sizer.Add(self.resetButton, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI, self.OnUpdateUI, self.resetButton)
        return sizer

    def OnZoomIn(self, event):
        self.canvas.Zoom(1.2)
        event.Skip()

    def OnZoomOut(self, event):
        self.canvas.Zoom(1/1.2)
        event.Skip()

    def OnPanLeft(self, event):
        self.canvas.Move(-0.1, 0)
        event.Skip()

    def OnPanRight(self, event):
        self.canvas.Move(0.1, 0)
        event.Skip()

    def OnReset(self, event):
        self.canvas.Reset()
        event.Skip()

    def OnUpdateUI(self, event):
        if self.canvas.CanReset():
            self.resetButton.Enable(True)
        else:
            self.resetButton.Enable(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainWindow(None, title='Telemetry EFT')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And here is a link to the example data file : [data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ZJfKXOhmTqTgHJQ7QfCLMTDZXP7DGF7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Seems like a typo. Try ```self.canvas.Draw(self.drawBrakeThrottlePlot())```.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that is not the error, I originally wrote it this way but had to remove the parenthesis as the function is not supposed to get an argument.

Comment: You are missing the ```self``` argument in ```drawBrakeThrottlePlot()```. You need to learn the Python syntax and error messages. After the second look, your code have so many errors. For example, the first arguments of ```PolyLine()``` calls should be like ```list(zip(time, brake_p))``` and the ```width``` arguments should not be a string.  I recommend you to write a unit test module.